# Renaming multiple files by name

Tags: vb.net, sorting, file-rename

I'm writing a little program that is supposed to rename multiple files in a chosen directory by the filenames.
this is what I use now:

```
    Dim sourcePath As String = dir
    Dim searchPattern As String = "*." & ComboBox3.Text
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        File.Move(Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName), Path.Combine(sourcePath, type & i & "." & ComboBox3.Text))
        i += 1
    Next
```

But i want it to be more like:

```
    For Each fi As FileInfo In Directory.GetFiles(searchPattern).OrderBy(Function(s) s.FullName)
        File.Move(Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName), Path.Combine(sourcePath, type & i & "." & ComboBox3.Text))
        i += 1
    Next
```

This is how far I've gotten, but it's not working as i hoped. 
Also, I was wondering if it is possible to exclude file-types with the GetFiles, i don't want it to rename text-files.

Thanks :)

**Edit:** 
The first code works almost perfect, it takes the dir from a 'FolderBrowserDialog' and renames all the files within the path-folder. The problem is that it sometimes get the order wrong: lets say i got these 3 files:

01Movie.avi, 07Movie.avi and 11Movie.avi

I want them to be renamed in the order they are in the folder by name:

01Movie.avi should be Movie1.avi, 07Movie.avi -> Movie2.avi and 11Movie.avi -> Movie3.avi

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail. Provide sample folder contents and how the code should search it, i.e. expected vs actual results.

Comment: @Neolisk  Tried to give a better description under edit. sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: it "gets the order wrong" because you are modifying the collection you are iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to modify a collection you are still looping through.  Created a detatched array to work with.  Then sort your new array to get them in the order you described.

Keep in mind that you have `SearchOption.AllDirectories`, this is going to return subs, so your filename array may not be what you were thinking... Either change the logic of the sort or handle subs separately.

```
'detached array of file names
 Dim fileNames() As String = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, searchPattern)

 'sort the names  System.Array.Sort(Of String)(fileNames)
 Dim newFileName As String  
 For Each fileName As String In fileNames

   'manipulate you filename here    
   'Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) might help   
   'Path.GetExtension(fileName) might help

    newFileName =  "newFileNameWithoutExtension" & i.ToString

    File.Move(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), fileName), Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), newFileName))
     i += 1  
 Next
```